# How to make the button not resize in width when the screen size gets smaller?

Tags: html, css

I want the button not to change its size in width when the screen size gets smaller. What should I do to keep the shape of the *Add admin* button the same?

This is how the button shanges its shape:
[My buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkFlF.png)

I want the shape to stay like this:
[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZndJ.png)

Here is my CSS code:

```
.button {
    background-color: black;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 25px;
```

Comment: Do you have any set width on those buttons? Check by using the inspector tools, just in case.

Comment: Are you talking about the button keeping its shape rather than keeping its size (in fixed units)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `white-space: nowrap;`

```
.button {
    background-color: black;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to widen the buttons at all
Just control the text so that it does not break the line on different devices

```
.button { 
    ...
    white-space  : nowrap;
    overflow     : hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{

min-width: (desired value) px!important;
max-width: (desired value) px!important;
}
```

Putting a static value should work :) Put them the same value if you want the exact same in all devices :)